# Lambda throws error depending on how zip is created

Tags: node.js, lambda, gulp

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
gulp.task('newInstanceSetup', function() {
    return gulp.src('./**/*',{cwd:'./new_instance_setup'})
        .pipe(zip('archive.zip'))
        .pipe(lambda(newInstanceSetup_params, opts))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

This causes errors when the code is executed by AWS Lambda.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'async'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:5:9)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:409:26)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:343:32)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)"
  ]
}
```

If I manually zip and upload the contents of the folder (select all > right click > 7-zip > add to archive...) it'll create an archive that **works** with Lambda.

If I manually upload the `archive.zip` created by the gulp process, Lambda will throw an error when executing the code. That leads me to believe that the error is somewhere in the gulp zipping process.

If I inspect both of the archives the filesize is different, but the contents look the same at first glance.

`zip` is from [gulp-zip](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip)

Comment: Are you zipping up the `node_modules`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I believe so. That's what the `gulp.src` command is intended to do. After eyeballing it, it looks like the node_modules dir and all subdirs are there, in the gulp-generated archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-zip/issues/64

This happens because of a permissions issue between Windows and Linux. Add `{nodir:true}` to the options when you specify `gulp.src`

My code becomes: `gulp.src('./**/*',{cwd:'./new_instance_setup',nodir:true})`